# ClassFormatException Tag file Jsp/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tagfile

I get "The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"(on my browser)". Also on my Tomcat console its shows ClassFormatException.

I read about the same problems occurred to other developers but the solution provided was in relation to IDE. I am not using Eclipse or any IDE.

My JDK Version is: jdk1.8.0_05
Apache Tomcat: 7.0.14

I am learning to make JSP tag file. Here are the two files that have coded.

JSP File(tagfile.jsp)(file location:The root directory)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="h" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

    <h:greeting personName="Karan"></h:greeting>
```

Tag file(greeting.tag)(file location: "/WEB-INF/tags")

```
<%@tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<%@attribute name="personName" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<jsp:doBody var = "message" />
${message} ${name}
```

Comment: Tomcat is also running on Java 8?

Comment: how do i determine that(windows)?

Comment: @Henry its jvm version 1.8.0._05-b13